# How to configure Azure DevOps Pipeline decorators to run pre-tasks in classic pipelines?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-decorator

We have a custom Azure DevOps extension to in order to inject SonarQube pipeline tasks into every definition using the Pipeline Decorator feature. These tasks are a mixutre of both ***pre*** and ***post*** tasks.

In YAML defined pipelines, the tasks run perfectly, however in Classic pipeline definitions, only the ***post*** tasks run, although the classic and YAML pipelines are defined identically (steps, agents, demands, variables etc.).

As this is a relatively new feature of Azure DevOps, there is a lack of documentation, especially regarding classic pipelines.

Is there something that we could possibly be missing for this to happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there something that we could possibly be missing for this to
>   happen?

This seems the issue on our side. And, it only exists to the sonarcloud/sonarqube **prepare** task if we apply it into **Decorator**.

As you know, users use `yaml` template for the steps to inserted at the specified location. And in fact, on our backend, this template file is processed through **yaml template engine**.

As our design, after you enable the `Pipeline decorators` at organization level. In **Initialize job**, `Pipeline` will call one backend class to get the `JobContext`, which will add `decorator providers` to `JobContext`. Then `JobContext` use these providers to fetch contributions to add `pre/post` tasks in job while preparing the job to run.

BUT, the `sonar prepare` task can not **actively** be detected by engine, then inject it into `JobContext`. For why I point to this specific task, because this kind of abnormality only exists in the **prepare** task of `sonarcloud` and `sonarqube` until now.

*Our team will do some investigation and fix with sonar team together.*

---

Until now, there has 2 work around you could consider to apply.

**Work around 1:**

As I mentioned previously, this `prepare` task can not actively be detected and injected into `JobContext`. So, the first work around we actively add this task info into `JobContext` via adding `prepare` task into agent job.

But this will cause one disadvantage is, it will load 2 prepare tasks. One is executed in pre-job, and next it will run second.

[image]

**Work around 2:**

Try to use YAML to build your pipeline until we implement this abnormality thing. So that it will not cause error because of lacking `prepare` task

---

*Will update the status here to let you know once we have any progress.*

Comment: Thanks for the information. By ***actively add this task info into JobContext via adding prepare task into agent job***, you mean add this task in manually to every pipeline, or is there a way we can inject this into `JobContext` using the decorator?

Comment: @Harry, **JobContext** is the one which generated by backend class. For you, you need manually add this prepare task into agent job. Note, only pipeline which is configured by Classic UI need this. I have contact the corresponding team and let them know this abnormality today.

Comment: Do you have any updates on the state of this @Merlin? Thanks!

Comment: This issue is still not solved. Any decorator task in Classic RM with some kind of data will fail to inject automatically without adding it manually (= without workaround 1).

Comment: Found out why, had a custom decorator myself with setting serviceconnections as input. Instead of doing that, setting the serviceconnection name in the task input `defaultValue` seems to work!

Comment: Not tested any further, but I'm guessing that for Classic RM the serviceconnection name will not be resolved to a guid. Which most of us don't want to hardcode, as a guid of a serviceconnection is likely to be different if you want to go multi tenant or even per teamproject.